# Как задать data-* атрибут в строго типизированном хелпере asp.net mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

> Внимание! Это перевод вопроса [ASP.NET MVC Adding Attribute
>   “data-message” to
>   Html.TextBoxFor](//stackoverflow.com/questions/19596232/asp-net-mvc-adding-attribute-data-message-to-html-textboxfor)

Необходимо вывести в элемент формы дополнительный data-атрибут:

```
<input name="file" type="file" class="file" data-show-preview="false">
```

Как это сделать при помощи строго типизированного хелпера? Следующий вариант не проходит:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.File, new { type = "file", data-show-preview = "false", @class = "file" })
```

Выдаётся ошибка:

> Invalid anonymous type member declarator. Anonymous type members must
>   be declared with a member assignment, simple name or member access.

Comment: ассоциация:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19596232/

Answer (score 1):

Используйте символ подчёркивания вместо дефиса в названии data-атрибута:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.File, new { type = "file", data_show_preview = "false", @class = "file" })
```

Хелпер TextBoxFor знает что делать и заменит во время генерации разметки символы подчёркивания обратно на дефисы.